# How to extract ca chain from a pem certificate file

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, certificate, private-key

I am trying to find out a method to extract ca cert chain(root and the intermediate cert) from a pem certificate

We have the pem certificate with private key and chain, and i use below method to extract private key. How i can get the chain extracted from same pem cert. ?

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

with open(pem_file_path, "rb") as pem_file:
     pem_data = pem_file.read()

private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(pem_data, password=password) 
pem_private_key = private_key.private_bytes( encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM, format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8, encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption() ).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Just to be sure: which headers are in your PEM file? I presume you've tried [`load_pem_x509_certificates`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.load_pem_x509_certificates)?